# Android DriveQuickstart Drive API- 400 Bad Request

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

i'm testing Android DriveQuickstart with Google Drive API,
while trying out the sample code to access Drive using API i got the following error.

**400 Bad Request
message: Invalid field selection items**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 400: Bad Request
>
> User error. This can mean that a required field or parameter has not
>   been provided, the value supplied is invalid, or the combination of
>   provided fields is invalid.

This error must be referring to this line of code:

```
FileList result = mService.files().list()
                 .setPageSize(10)
                 .setFields("nextPageToken, items(id, name)")
                 .execute();
```

Change `.setFields("nextPageToken, items(id, name)")` to

```
setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
```

---

Comment: Drive Api Call worked.But i just happen to see only the name of the files in the drive. Any explanation on the above change of code ,kindly let me know.